# simtk.openmm.app.internal.charmm.exceptions.CharmmFileError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../toppar/top_all36_prot.rtf'

Tags: python, hpcc

I am trying to run an OpenMM simulation on HPCC, but I get the error that 'top_all36_prot.rtf' file, which is an rtf file, is not into my directory - while I have copied that file into my directory. would you please help me how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely because HPCC Systems Platform runs as user hpcc and the OpenMM installed as your user.  You will need to install OpenMM for all users and restart the platform.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).